# Why is the anchor north west ignored?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

In the following snippet, I'd expect the nodes to be perfectly aligned vertically. But it looks like the anchor is ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}
\newcommand{\imgwidth}{2cm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[inner sep=5, draw, rectangle] (baz) {\includegraphics[height=\imgwidth,width=\imgwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
%
      \node[inner sep=5, draw, rectangle, anchor=north west, below=of baz.south west] (bar)
      {\includegraphics[width=\imgwidth,height=\imgwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
%
      \node[inner sep=5, draw, rectangle, anchor=north west, below=of bar.south west] (foo)
      {\includegraphics[width=\imgwidth,height=\imgwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why is the anchor not used for the layout?

Comment: because it overwritten with `below=of bar.south west`. if you like that the anchor is considered, it has to be lat between options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as i mentioned in comment, the anchor had to be last between option of your node (slightly shortened code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}
\newcommand{\imgwidth}{2cm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={rectangle, draw, inner sep=5}]
      \node (baz) 
      {\includegraphics[height=\imgwidth,width=\imgwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
%
      \node[below=of baz.south west, anchor=north west] (bar)
      {\includegraphics[width=\imgwidth,height=\imgwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
%
      \node[below=of bar.south west,anchor=north west] (foo)
      {\includegraphics[width=\imgwidth,height=\imgwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

however, the same result you can obtain with more simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\imgwidth}{2cm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={rectangle, draw, inner sep=5}]
      \node (baz) {\includegraphics[height=\imgwidth,width=\imgwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
%
      \node[below=of baz] (bar)
      {\includegraphics[width=\imgwidth,height=\imgwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
%
      \node[below=of bar] (foo)
      {\includegraphics[width=\imgwidth,height=\imgwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]